# WiX: property value lost between InstallUISequence and InstallExecuteSequence

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer

I'm facing an issue with my [WiX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX) installer.

I have a custom dialog that contains an edit control linked to a property. At runtime, if I change the value in the edit control, I see from the log that the property is properly updated with that new value. But it seems that, when the [InstallUISequence](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_installuisequence.htm) ends, the property is reset to its default value, which is annoying, because I cannot use the user sumitted value in a custom action part of the [InstallExecuteSequence](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_installexecutesequence.htm).

Here is an extract of the WXS script I use:

```
<UI>
    <Dialog Id="select_list" Width="370" Height="270" Title="Select license and list files">
        <Control Id="BannerBitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="44" TabSkip="no" Text="UIBannerBmp" />
        <Control Id="BannerLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="45" Width="370" Height="0" />
        <Control Id="BottomLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="234" Width="370" Height="0" />
        <Control Type="Edit" Id="list" Width="211" Height="15" X="128" Y="128" Property="pListFile" />
        <Control Type="Text" Id="static_list" Width="78" Height="17" X="41" Y="154" Text="list file" />
        <Control Type="PushButton" Id="next" Width="50" Height="17" X="232" Y="244" Text="Next &gt;">
            <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return">1</Publish>
        </Control>
        <Control Type="PushButton" Id="cancel" Width="50" Height="17" X="296" Y="244" Text="Cancel">
            <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg">1</Publish>
        </Control>
        <Control Type="Text" Id="desc" Width="348" Height="16" X="8" Y="90"
                 Text="Please set the path of the the list file" />
    </Dialog>

    <InstallUISequence>
        <Show Dialog="select_list" After="WelcomeEulaDlg">NOT installed</Show>
    </InstallUISequence>
</UI>

<CustomAction Id="InstallService"
              ExeCommand="[bin]prog.exe -f install.cl '[pListFile]'"
              Execute="immediate"
              Return="check"
              Directory="bin" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="InstallService" After="InstallFinalize">REMOVE=""</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>

<CustomActionRef Id="InstallService" />
<Property Id="pListFile" Value="c:\" />
```

I must not be on the right track to exchange information between the two sequences.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to mark the Property "Secure" for it to pass from the client-side (InstallUISequence) to server-side (InstallExecuteSequence). To do that you need to make the Property "public" (ALL CAPS) and secure. Something like so:

`<Property Id="PLISTFILE" Secure="yes"/>`

You don't need to give it a value unless you want something to show up by in your UI by default.