# WiX - altering text in ExitDialog depending on result of an action after InstallFinalize

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action

I would like to alter text in ExitDialog depending on result of an immediate action, executed after InstallFinalize. I have tried to do this with the use of property to be set by the action (ISSUCCEEDED in the snippet below), but as I understand it, installer lost this property after the transition from server to client phase. If so, how this could be done?

```
<!-- The MyAction sets the property ISSUCCEEDED -->
<CustomAction Id="MyAction" BinaryKey="..." DllEntry="..."/>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
   <Custom Action="MyAction" After="InstallFinalize">...</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
<UI>
  <Dialog Id="MyExitDialog" ...>
     ...
     <!-- ISSUCCEEDED is lost by now -->
     <Control Id="C1" Type="Text" Hidden="yes" Text="!(loc.Text1)"...>
        <Condition Action="show">ISSUCCEEDED</Condition>                    
     </Control>
     <Control Id="C2" Type="Text" Hidden="yes" Text="!(loc.Text2)"...>
        <Condition Action="show">NOT ISSUCCEEDED</Condition>                    
     </Control>
     ...    
  </Dialog>
</UI>
```

Comment: Try to [mark the property as "secure"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1335920/7571258).

Comment: @zett42 no, that didn't help me either.

Comment: Sorry I can't help you further. It's a long time ago when I last dealt with built-in UI .